# Puppet error : could not retrieve catalog from remote server: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise, puppetlabs-apache

I am trying to setup puppet master and puppet agent in aws ec2 instances-linux ami. when i run my puppet agent to generate the certificate for the master to sign i encounter the below error.

Puppet Master:

```
[root@ip-10-**-*-*** /]# sudo yum install puppet-server

[root@ip-10-**-*-*** /] sudo service puppetmaster start
Starting puppetmaster:                                     [  OK  ]
```

Puppet Agent:

```
[root@ip-10-**-*-*** /]# sudo yum install puppet

[root@ip-10-**-*-*** /]
File excerpt /etc/puppet/puppet.conf
[main]
     server = hostname

[root@ip-10-**-*-*** /] sudo service puppet start
Starting puppet:                                           [  OK  ]

[root@ip-10-**-*-*** /]# puppet agent -t
    info: Creating a new SSL key for ip-10-**-*-***.dev.abc.net
    info: Caching certificate for ca
    info: Creating a new SSL certificate request for ip-10-**-*-***.dev.abc.net
    info: Certificate Request fingerprint (md5): C2:F0:B1:2C:19:39:9E:D6:39:24:18:28
    Exiting; no certificate found and waitforcert is disabled
```

Puppet Master:

```
[root@ip-10-**-*-*** /]# puppet cert list
"ip-10-**-*-***.dev.abc.net" (C2:F0:B1:2C:19:39:9E:D6:39:24:18:28:F6:DA:5D:FE)

[root@ip-10-**-*-*** /]# puppet cert sign ip-10-**-*-***.dev.abc.net
notice: Signed certificate request for ip-10-**-*-***.dev.abc.net
notice: Removing file Puppet::SSL::CertificateRequest ip-10-**-*-***.dev.abc.net at '/var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca/requests/ip-10-**-*-***.dev.abc.net.pem'
```

Puppet Agent:

```
[root@ip-10-**-*-*** /]# puppet agent -t
info: Caching certificate for ip-10-**-*-***.dev.abc.net
err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed: [certificate signature failure for /CN=ip-10-**-*-***.dev.abc.net]
warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
err: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
err: Could not send report: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed: [certificate signature failure for /CN=ip-10-**-*-***.dev.abc.net]
```

Can anyone please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Masterless puppet is honestly the common route for cloud provisioning with Puppet. Is that feasible for you?

Comment: The agent was unable to establish an (SSL) connection with the master.  My first guess would be that you haven't opened the necessary port in the master's firewall.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I know this is an old post. It still needs an answer, as I am having the same issue -- been working it for a few weeks now. I cannot guarantee yet that mine is working correctly all the time. Here are some steps I have taken. I hope they are helpful to others.
I am running Puppet Enterprise 2018.1.4. Puppet Agent 5.5.6 on RHEL 7.4.
1) The SSL routine uses a time stamp. Ensure the time is the same between Master & Client.
2) clean/remove the agent cert from the Master AND the Client. On my RHEL, the Client cert is is in /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/* -- remove any files with the agent name in here.
3) Make sure your puppet enabled on your agent: puppet agent --enable
4) If a client does not contact the puppet master "for a while" the master will drop the client from it's node list, but NOT remove the cert. In theory, the master SHOULD return the node to an active status.
5) Can you run the puppet agent on the master & get the expected results? If not -> problem with puppet code, otherwise, problem with agent.
6) Is puppet.conf configured correctly?
 Under the [main] section, do you have the server entry correct? 
Under [agent] are you set to the correct environment? Is noop set to true?
7) It is possible that you have an error in a puppet module that is causeing the agent to exit quietly. Run puppet parser validate on all of your .pp files
8) Can the master resolve the IP address of the master and the client? 
Can the client resolve the the IP address of the master and the client? 
Is resolv.conf set correctly on both hosts?
9) hostnames of the client & master should be correct. Each server should know it's shortname, FQDN and IP. On RHEL, I run: hostname; hostname -f; and hostname -i, respectively.
10) File permissions on all the directories & modules should be correct. Check out a working module, see it's owner, group & permissions. Ensure your module is the same.
11) Only root/admin can correctly run puppet agent.
12) On RHEL, the logs are under /var/log/puppet. Do you see any errors there?
13) run puppet agent with the --debug or the --trace option in addition to -t. Pipe this output to a file and see if you can spot any errors.
14) Can you force the master to run the puppet agent on the client successfully?
Many of these things have been narrowing down my issue. I don't know yet if it is fixed, as It takes a while for a node to drop out. Hopefully these will fix your issue.

Comment: I'm glad you noticed this is a little bit of a "wall of text". Formatting here is really quite easy once you get used to it. Here's a good resource https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.

Comment: Also make sure you stop/start the puppet agent, as even though it might show the right thumbprint, I think it loads the key on startup and does NOT refresh it, so replacing keys may result in `Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey: key values mismatch` from the agent run intervals